Saving a file as pdf and docx using VBA
I'm new to VBA, trying to make a simple macro that will both save a document in word as docx and also print > print to pdf using bioPDF.
When I run it and try to open the file produced in Adobe it says it cannot open because its is either a not supported file type or because the file has been damaged.
Tried using this code:
Sub PrintToPDFAndSaveAsDocx()
    Dim fullPath As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim folder As String
    Dim folderNew As String
   
    name = InputBox("Please enter a filename:")
    folder = InputBox("Either enter a folder to save to or leave blank and click ok")
   
    If Len(folder) > 1 Then
        folderNew = folder & "\"
    Else
        folderNew = folder
    End If
  
    fullPath = "P:\My Documents\" & folderNew & name & ".pdf"
   
    Application.ActivePrinter = "PDF Writer - bioPDF"
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut OutputFileName:=fullPath
    Application.ActivePrinter = "HP PageWide MFP P77740-60 PCL-6 (V4) (Network)"
   
    Dim docxPath As String
    docxPath = "P:\My Documents\" & folderNew & name & ".docx"

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=docxPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
End Sub


Edit: I should probably mention its word 2016 I'm using it in.

What does printing to bioPDF give you that SaveAs or ExportAsFixedFormat won't?

@TimothyRylatt I believe SaveAs is lower quality, people complain about fonts not looking the same or being as crisp and the file is smaller. No idea about ExportAsFixedFormat mostly I'm just following directions for how the company want it done but maybe I can look into that.

Customize your Quick Access Toolbar and add the command "Publish as PDF or XPS".  This is the UI equivalent of ExportAsFixedFormat. You will find that there are additional options to help control the quality of the file. The only issues with fonts tend to arise when using fonts that cannot be embedded, as they then need to be bitmapped.

Thanks for the advice @TimothyRylatt I've set it up with ExportAsFixedFormat, looks fine to me but I've sent it over to one of the guys who will be using it for testing so fingers crossed.

Have you tried recording a macro to save a file as pdf / docx?
Here's an example I recorded in Word 2016 (save as PDF).
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "C:\Users\*User name*\Desktop\Документ Microsoft Word.pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

